# How to replace all the various empty values in a dataframe so that they are all NaN, not '-' or others

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

As the title says, I have a dataset that has empty values. The problem is that some of them are represented by a `'-'` and some by `NaN`.

Is it better to change all of them to `NaN` or to `'-'`?

Comment: Are you sure they are `NaM`s not `NaN`s?

Comment: Btw we cannot tell you what's "better", depends what you want.

Comment: Yes, i meant NaN. Sorry

Comment: (Np, you can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63971941/edit) your Q.)

Comment: If you are reading dataset from a file, may be you can use `na_values` parameter and then call replace instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['Alpha','Beta','Gamma','-','Kappa','Delta','-','Zeta']})
>>> df
       A
0  Alpha
1   Beta
2  Gamma
3      -
4  Kappa
5  Delta
6      -
7   Zeta

>>> df.replace('-',np.nan)
       A
0  Alpha
1   Beta
2  Gamma
3    NaN
4  Kappa
5  Delta
6    NaN
7   Zeta
```

Comment: If your problem was resolved, please read about what to do when someone [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) your question.

Answer (score 6):

You could use `fillna` for same, which is designed to do these kind of tasks.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df.fillna("-")
```

Comment: wow! i had no idea this is a thing, thanks

Comment: @adamDud, your welcome, cheers we all learn new things(even I am learning pandas :) ), happy learning

Comment: ++ `df.fillna` is the right way of handling this